# preg_match - need to get a string out of an url

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to get a string out of some youtube urls looking like that:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/WJlfVjGt6Hg?list=EC1512BD72E7C9FFCA&amp;hl=en_US
```

I need to get the variables between"../embed/" and "?list=.." (-> **WJlfVjGt6Hg** ).

The code for the other youtube urls looks like this:

```
// Checks for YouTube iframe, the new standard since at least 2011
if ( !isset( $matches[1] ) ) {
    preg_match( '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#', $markup, $matches );}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

It's the base name of the path from your url:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/WJlfVjGt6Hg?list=EC1512BD72E7C9FFCA&amp;hl=en_US';
echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
// WJlfVjGt6Hg
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't consider that you can ask for just one part of the URL.

Comment: You 1-upped me, used basename() instead. +1 then =oP

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression.  Not every problem that involves a string is best solved with regexes.

Use the `parse_url()` function, built in to PHP, to break apart the parts for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php is the manual page for it.  Here's how you use it:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/WJlfVjGt6Hg?list=EC1512BD72E7C9FFCA&amp;hl=en_US';

$parts = parse_url( $url );
print_r( $parts );

$path_parts = explode( '/', $parts['path'] );
print_r( $path_parts );

$last_part = $path_parts[count($path_parts)-1];

print "Youtube video ID = $last_part\n";
```

And when you run that, you get this:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.youtube.com
    [path] => /embed/WJlfVjGt6Hg
    [query] => list=EC1512BD72E7C9FFCA&amp;hl=en_US
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => embed
    [2] => WJlfVjGt6Hg
)
Youtube video ID = WJlfVjGt6Hg
```

Comment: That's seriously complex for such a simple problem :)

Comment: I don't think that two function calls and an array lookup are complex.  The `print_r`s are for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use the following regular expression:

```
/embed\/([^\?]+)/
```

A short explanation - this matches all characters after 'embed/' that aren't a question mark, until it finds a question mark.

Here's a sample script which shows you the output you're looking for:

```
<?php

$test="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WJlfVjGt6Hg?list=EC1512BD72E7C9FFCA&amp;hl=en_US";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/embed\/([^\?]+)/', $test, $matches);
print_r($matches);
// The value we're looking for is in index 1 of the array
echo $matches[1];
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => embed/WJlfVjGt6Hg
[1] => WJlfVjGt6Hg
)
WJlfVjGt6Hg
```

Comment: sry i am a complete newbe :/ i dont get it
i tried the code above but it didnt work.
could someone give me the excact code which i have to place in this script?

Comment: This code will get you what you're looking for. What is the code that isn't working?

Comment: preg_match( '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([^\?]+)/', $markup, $matches );

Comment: Try this: `preg_match( '#https?://www\.youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/embed/([^\?]+)#', $markup, $matches );` By using the '#' symbol as the starting character, that becomes your regex delimiter , so you need one at the end as well.

Comment: ok i think this works now... many thx! another question: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13_6ZcHF_gc&list=PLF0BF7A216C0B9F5A&feature=player_embedded (how do i extract this code "13_6ZcHF_gc"? is this correct: '#(?:https?(?:a|vh?)?://)?(?:www\.)?youtube(?:\-nocookie)?\.com/watch\?.*v=([^\&]+)#'

Comment: @Mark37 Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you do this without any positive lookaheads? Would this expression not work? 

`/embed\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/`

You could then access the output with the index 1, as you specified before.

Comment: @laurenz I would suggest actually learning regular expressions instead of asking us to write them all for you. It seems like you're just fishing for answers rather than just trying to learn how to use them yourself. You can use a site like this to test regular expressions: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @Michael - I think that would work so long as the string you're looking for is only alphanumeric, however I'm not 100% sure that's the case.  I think if you were doing that you could probably just do `/embed\/(\w+)/` as well.

Comment: thank you so far! i think i now understand a little bit more and the code works (i think :) )

Comment: @laurenz You should not be using regular expressions for retrieving parts of a URL. PHP has functions already in place to do that which are faster and not likely to break if the URL format changes.